# jQuery / Javascript insert element after the current paragraph in content editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, figure

I am using [Medium.js](http://jakiestfu.github.io/Medium.js/docs/) editor script which helps with `contenteditable` `div`s.

But I also want to make adding images better and more like Medium.js itself does.

Currently, I am using this function to insert a node at the current cursor point:

```
function insertImageAtCursor(text) {
    var sel, range, html;
    sel = window.getSelection();
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    range.deleteContents();

    var descriptionNode = document.createElement("img");
    descriptionNode.className = "img";
    descriptionNode.src = text;

    range.insertNode(descriptionNode);
    range.setStartAfter(descriptionNode);

    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}
```

This works, however I am facing styling issues where I am currently in a paragraph and typing, then insert an image I will end up with content like:

```
<p>
    this is a paragraph and I have inserted a image
    <img src="insertimage.png"/>
</p>
```

Really, I should be using the `figure` element and it would insert the image outside of the current paragraph. This way when I add an image, it wouldn't be added in the current `p` element, but instead would be added after and as a `figure` element. I cannot simply append the image, as I want users to be able to be editing a blog post and be able to insert an image at any point.

Any help on this? There is a plugin already:

But the dependencies required are more than I wish to use and I already have image upload etc working. Just need to get the images being inserted better.

Comment: The link to the plugin is missing, could you restore it please?

Answer (score 0):

you can split the `<p>` in two `<p>` tags and add the `<img>` between this `<p>` tags.
Here is a sample code. It's not bug free :).

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaOpbr

```
function insertImageAtCursor(text) {
    var sel, range, html;
    sel = window.getSelection();
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

    var para = getParagraph(range.startContainer);
        range.deleteContents();

    range.setEndAfter(para);

    var newPara = document.createElement("p");
    newPara.innerHTML = range.toString();
    range.deleteContents();

    para.parentElement.appendChild(newPara);
    para.parentElement.insertBefore(para, newPara);

    var descriptionNode = document.createElement("img");
    descriptionNode.className = "img";
    descriptionNode.src = text;

    para.parentElement.insertBefore(descriptionNode, newPara);

    range.setStart(newPara, 0);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}

function getParagraph(node) {
  var para = node;
  while (para.parentElement !== null && (para.tagName == null || para.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'p')) {

    para = para.parentElement;
  }
  return para;
}
```